# Change position of Collade object over time in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, loader, collada

I am using the elf example that is a standard example with [ThreeJS](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html)

Instead of the rotation shown in the example I want to move the object in both the x and y direction. This should be achievable by changing `elf.position.x` and `elf.position.y` in the init() function.

This issue I am facing it that I created an object(class) of the methods that create an elf so I can create multiple ones. I also have a function that should move the object over time. `var e` is not accessible in the move function. When I change it to `this.e` and I change this `e = collada.scene;` to `this.e = collada.scene;` I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'e' of undefined`

Code:

```
 class DrawElf {
    constructor(scene) {
        var e;
        this.loadingManager = {};
        this.loader = {};
        this.scene = scene;

        // loading manager
        this.loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager(function () {
            scene.add(e);
        });

        // collada
        this.loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader(this.loadingManager);
        this.loader.load('./models/collada/elf/elf.dae', function (collada) {
            e = collada.scene;
            e.scale.set(30, 30, 30);
            e.position.set(100, 10, 100);
            e.name = "elf.dae" + 0 + 0;

            e.traverse(function (child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    child.name = e.name;
                    ToIntersect.push(child);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    move(time) {
        // i want to move the object
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone can help out.

Comment: Do you have a running example of the code? At first glance you won't have access to the `e` variable from the `move` function to move the model and you're using `self` instead of `this` for defining class variables (unless you mean to access `window` here).

Comment: @GarrettJohnson My bad, I meant to use this instead of self but the error still remains. Unfortunately, I don't have a publicly available running example. I am running everything locally. If I am not mistaken, if I initialise a variable with this.something in the constructor I should have access to said variable anywhere through my class. What am I doing differently here?

Comment: Your `e` variable isn't available by accessing `this`. I've added an answer with some changes to your example code that should hopefully help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited your example code to show how to access the elf model in the `move()` function and called out the changes in comments below.

```
class DrawElf {
    constructor(scene) {

        // Change 1: Place the `e` variable on `this` so it's accessible
        // from member functions like `move`
        this.e = null;
        this.loadingManager = {};
        this.loader = {};
        this.scene = scene;

        // Change 2: Use arrow functions instead so that the scope of the
        // constructor is retained in the callback and `this` still references
        // the new `DrawElf` instance 
        // collada
        this.loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        this.loader.load('./models/collada/elf/elf.dae', (collada) => {
            this.e = collada.scene;
            this.e.scale.set(30, 30, 30);
            this.e.position.set(100, 10, 100);
            this.e.name = "elf.dae" + 0 + 0;

            this.e.traverse(function (child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    child.name = this.e.name;
                    ToIntersect.push(child);
                }
            });


            // Change 3: Remove the loading manager because it's not needed to
            // add the elf to the scene and instead do so here
            scene.add(this.e);
        });
    }

    move(time) {
        // Change 4: Check if the scene has been loaded before trying to move
        // the model
        if (this.e) {
            // move the model here
        }
    }
}
```

The big change here is to use arrow functions instead of the original Javascript functions so `this` still references the object instance being constructed. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch) should explain the differences in scoping a bit more.

Hopefully that helps! Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: @GarretJohnson Thank you very much. Your answer and the link attached were very helpful. I noticed that when I ran your code I received an error on this line `child.name = e.name;`. Rewriting that function using the arrow syntax fixed everything.

Comment: Oh I missed that referenced. I've updated the answer to use `child.name = this.e.name;`. Glad to help!

Comment: Thanks again. Based on what I read on the link you attached and your reply, won't the code as it is raise the following error `Cannot read property 'e' of undefined`? And would rewriting `this.e.traverse` using the arrows syntax fix it? (at least for me it did)

Comment: Your code will run and all the function callbacks will have access to the `e` variable because it's defined locally in a parent scope. However, `this.e` is undefined and you won't be able to access `e` in the `move` function, which is what you need in order to animate the model.

Comment: Thank you for your additional reply.